# Makefile.in Makefile.am files

Tags: linux, c++

Can you please tell me what are the differences between `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`?
What about `acinclude.m4` and `aclocal.m4` files?  I am trying to compile a cpp project on Linux.

Comment: Do you have root permissions on this machine?  What distro of Linux?  Ubuntu? Redhat? Suse?

Answer (score 2):

- `Makefile.am` is the `automake` source file.
- `Makefile.in` is generated by `automake` from `Makefile.am`